# Is this a Stack Overflow or a Webmaster question?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/24090/shoutcast-song-history-purchase-search-from-website a Stack Overflow or a Webmaster question?

I would have appreciated the topic being moved rather than just closed.

Comment: Isn't this something you'd need to ask your server provider directly? You've not said what data you actually get other than "some Java Script"

Comment: @Moif: As a side note, you could have raised this issue by flagging your question for moderator attention, asking in [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7) or posting a question on the [WebApps Meta](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Ah ok. I wasn't aware of the Meta side. I should RTFM again. Thanks, Barry.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the original question is dead. There is no use in this question any more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq), the site where you posted the question, clearly states that is a site for questions about:

- Using Gmail, Facebook, Twitter, Google, or any other website which behaves like an application
- Bookmarklets
- Browsers and their features relating to the use of a web application (Greasemonkey scripts for a web application, etc.)

As your question is not about one of those topics, the question is off-topic there.

As there is a Stack Exchange site for [WordPress](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com), I would ask the question there. Between the two sites you are asking for (*Stack Overflow* and *Pro Webmasters*), the questions on the latter are the ones that generally cover the operation of websites which you control; as t[heir FAQ](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq) says, if the question is about detailed HTML, JavaScript, or CSS coding, it might be a better fit on Stack Overflow.

> I would have appreciated the topic being moved rather than just closed.

If somebody pointed out for which site the question was a better suit, then there could have been an exchange between the moderators of both the sites (which could be happened in this case too); if the moderators of the other site answered with a "yes, we can get the answer," then the question would have been migrated.
In general, if you are asking a question on the wrong site, and there are more than one site where the question could be asked, users in the site where you asked the question don't go looking for the right site for your question.

Comment: That's fair enough, thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score -2):

In order to do this type of requests, just flag the question and fill the "other" field with your request.